# If I have a game downloaded on my Xbox, can I transfer it to a disk?

Tags: xbox-360

I bought a digital copy of GTA V, but I heard that if you run a disk version there's less pop-in and lag. I don't know if this is true, but either way, is there a way to transfer an Xbox 360 game to an empty disc?

Comment: Nope.  Digital = digital.  If you were able to transfer it to disk, you could play it on a non-authorized system, and there's no way Microsoft or Sony would allow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no clean way of doing so. And for good reason.

The idea of purchasing a game through the Store / Marketplace is to remove the disc from the scenario. By not having a disc, you will permanently own the game without risk of getting lost or scratched into such a state it no longer works.

To be truthful, there is no difference in my opinion. The cause of this is usually down to your connection, or how strong the servers are running ... Also how well your console reads the disc. That can have major affect.

Hope this helps, enjoy your thug life.